# How to run an ocatve command from the terminal with several arguments including a matrix?

Tags: octave

I want to run a octave script from the terminal with several arguments.

consider the function

```
function matrixMultiply (A, x)
  result = A * x ; 
  presult = sprintf('%s %s\n', 'A * x =', mat2str(result));
  printf ("\a%s\n", presult);
endfunction
```

How can I call this function from the terminal. I tried using

```
arg_list = argv ();
for i = 1:nargin
  printf (" %s", arg_list{i});
printf ("\n");
endfor
```

in a separate script without luck.

How can I run

```
$ octave  matrixMultiply(eye(2) , [3;4])
```

from the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your function file without using `argv ()`

file matrixMultiply.m:

```
function matrixMultiply (A, x)
  result = A * x ; 
  presult = sprintf('%s %s\n', 'A * x =', mat2str(result));
  printf ("\a%s\n", presult);
endfunction
```

from terminal:

```
$ octave --eval "matrixMultiply(eye(2) , [3;4])"
A * x = [3;4]
```